# PHP DateTime avoid setting locale if only work with dates

Tags: php, datetime, internationalization

I'm using PHP DateTime with TimeZone to show time of an specific region. The problem is when I only work with dates, the DateTime object set time to now and when TimeZone is set the date changes +1day or -1day.

If I only work with dates, those shouldn't change.

How to avoid this using DateTime or another PHP object? (creating a custom Date object is a known solution).

I suppose lots of frameworks use internationalization and solve this problem. But how?